# Iterate over a dataframe to print the index and column and value

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, printing

First off, I am still new to Python and have searched and have been unable to find out anywhere how to do this (from a new person's perspective)...

I have a python

[image: DataFrame]

I need to print out the index, column name and value.

Let's say I have the following dataframe

```
EAT     DAILY  WEEKLY  YEARLY
Fruit                        
APPLE       2       5     200
ORANGE      1       3     100
BANANA      1       4     150
PEAR        0       1      40
```

I need to print it our such that I would get something like the following so that it iterates over every row in the dataframe.

```
Eat Apple Daily at least 2
Eat Apple Weekly at least 5
Eat Apple Yearly at least 200
Eat Orange Daily at least 1
Eat Orange Weekly at least 3
Eat Orange Yearly at least 100
..
...
....
```

I have tried various combinations but am still learning so any help is appreciated.

So far I have tried

```
for row in test.iterrows():
    index, data = row
    print index , (data['column1'])
    print index , (data['column2'])
    print index , (data['column3'])
```

Which will give me the index and value but not the column plus I'd like it to be able to iterate regardless how many columns or rows were used. Also, I still need to be able to insert the text which needs to be dynamic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Series of strings***

```
f = 'Eat {Fruit} {EAT} at least {value}'.format
df.stack().reset_index(name='value').apply(lambda x: f(**x), 1)

0         Eat APPLE DAILY at least 2
1        Eat APPLE WEEKLY at least 5
2      Eat APPLE YEARLY at least 200
3        Eat ORANGE DAILY at least 1
4       Eat ORANGE WEEKLY at least 3
5     Eat ORANGE YEARLY at least 100
6        Eat BANANA DAILY at least 1
7       Eat BANANA WEEKLY at least 4
8     Eat BANANA YEARLY at least 150
9          Eat PEAR DAILY at least 0
10        Eat PEAR WEEKLY at least 1
11       Eat PEAR YEARLY at least 40
dtype: object
```

***print out***

```
for idx, value in df.stack().iteritems():
    print('Eat {0[0]} {0[1]} at least {1}'.format(idx, value))

Eat APPLE DAILY at least 2
Eat APPLE WEEKLY at least 5
Eat APPLE YEARLY at least 200
Eat ORANGE DAILY at least 1
Eat ORANGE WEEKLY at least 3
Eat ORANGE YEARLY at least 100
Eat BANANA DAILY at least 1
Eat BANANA WEEKLY at least 4
Eat BANANA YEARLY at least 150
Eat PEAR DAILY at least 0
Eat PEAR WEEKLY at least 1
Eat PEAR YEARLY at least 40
```

Comment: I had come across the stack and interitems but wasn't sure of the syntax needed to get me to where I needed to be.  Worked exactly like I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape to `Series` with `MultiIndex` and then iterate by [`Series.iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) with `format`:

```
test = test.stack()
print (test)
Fruit   EAT   
APPLE   DAILY       2
        WEEKLY      5
        YEARLY    200
ORANGE  DAILY       1
        WEEKLY      3
        YEARLY    100
BANANA  DAILY       1
        WEEKLY      4
        YEARLY    150
PEAR    DAILY       0
        WEEKLY      1
        YEARLY     40
dtype: int64

for index, data in test.iteritems():
    print (('Eat {} {} at least {}').format(index[0], index[1], data))

Eat APPLE DAILY at least 2
Eat APPLE WEEKLY at least 5
Eat APPLE YEARLY at least 200
Eat ORANGE DAILY at least 1
Eat ORANGE WEEKLY at least 3
Eat ORANGE YEARLY at least 100
Eat BANANA DAILY at least 1
Eat BANANA WEEKLY at least 4
Eat BANANA YEARLY at least 150
Eat PEAR DAILY at least 0
Eat PEAR WEEKLY at least 1
Eat PEAR YEARLY at least 40
```

But if really need `DataFrame` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)and then loop by [`DataFrame.iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
test = test.stack().reset_index(name='VAL')
print (test)
     Fruit     EAT  VAL
0    APPLE   DAILY    2
1    APPLE  WEEKLY    5
2    APPLE  YEARLY  200
3   ORANGE   DAILY    1
4   ORANGE  WEEKLY    3
5   ORANGE  YEARLY  100
6   BANANA   DAILY    1
7   BANANA  WEEKLY    4
8   BANANA  YEARLY  150
9     PEAR   DAILY    0
10    PEAR  WEEKLY    1
11    PEAR  YEARLY   40

for index, data in test.iterrows():
    print (('Eat {} {} at least {}').format(data['Fruit'], data['EAT'], data['VAL']))

Eat APPLE DAILY at least 2
Eat APPLE WEEKLY at least 5
Eat APPLE YEARLY at least 200
Eat ORANGE DAILY at least 1
Eat ORANGE WEEKLY at least 3
Eat ORANGE YEARLY at least 100
Eat BANANA DAILY at least 1
Eat BANANA WEEKLY at least 4
Eat BANANA YEARLY at least 150
Eat PEAR DAILY at least 0
Eat PEAR WEEKLY at least 1
Eat PEAR YEARLY at least 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider even a non-loop solution using [pandas.DataFrame.to_string](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
sdf = df.stack().reset_index(name='VALUE')
sdf['Output'] = sdf.apply(lambda row: "EAT {} {} at least {}".\
                          format(row['Fruit'], row['EAT'], row['VALUE']), axis=1)

# PRINT TO CONSOLE
print(sdf[['Output']].to_string(header=False, index=False, justify='left'))

# WRITE TO TEXT
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(sdf[['Output']].to_string(header=False, index=False, justify='left'))

# EAT APPLE DAILY at least 2
#    EAT APPLE WEEKLY at least 5
#  EAT APPLE YEARLY at least 200
#    EAT ORANGE DAILY at least 1
#   EAT ORANGE WEEKLY at least 3
# EAT ORANGE YEARLY at least 100
#    EAT BANANA DAILY at least 1
#   EAT BANANA WEEKLY at least 4
# EAT BANANA YEARLY at least 150
#      EAT PEAR DAILY at least 0
#     EAT PEAR WEEKLY at least 1
#    EAT PEAR YEARLY at least 40
```

*You will notice a justification issue currently a [reported bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13032) on the method. Of course you can remedy with string handling (`strip()`, `replace()`) in general, base Python.*